# Why don't we need to pass an argument to onClick() in android

Tags: android, function

Here's the code

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.myButton.setOnClickListener (object: View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(**v: View?**) {
                binding.statusText.text = "Button Clicked"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Why does this code work when no argument is passed to onClick. I mean 'onClick()' takes a 'View' so we must call it like this: 'onClick(myButton)'.

Comment: Usually you don't call onClick yourself - for example, this code snippet has no such call. The framework calls it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically never call `onClick` yourself. The framework does it for you when you physically touch the view. And it will pass the view you actually touched.

You might wonder:

> Why does it even pass it?, I know which view I put the listener on

The thing is. You can give the same listener to multiple views. Having this as parameter makes you able to distinguish in the listener which of the views was clicked.

As a side note, this is a more idiomatic way to write it, and does exactly the same as your code

```
binding.myButton.setOnClickListener {
    binding.statusText.text = "Button Clicked"
}
```

Writing it like this, will have the view parameter available as `it`

Comment: Thank you so much. I think Google docs are a mess. Why didn't they add this line of yours `You typically never call onClick yourself. The framework does it for you when you physically touch the view. And it will pass the view you actually touched.` I don't think it would use up much space.

Answer (score 1):

The user interface control that is clicked, in this case a button, is a View, so it is passed as the argument to onClick().

Comment: Exactly! Short and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `View.OnClickListener` interface explicitly defines that the view that has been clicked is going to be passed to you.

You can certainly omit the value, but it's going to be there. Since it's a compiled language, in order to satisfy the interface you need to take that parameter regardless of whether you'll use it.

In JS world, which you may be getting confused with; is a dynamically typed language and hence in order for things to work you're just required to provide your callback. Either way, the parameters are still going to get passed into the function, but you'll not be referencing/using them